# fopen pass variables to remote servers

Tags: php

I'm using `fopen` to allow webmasters to access data directly from my web servers soon. The problem is my server doesn't see a few things it normally see's when its loading through JavaScript.

So I want to pass a few variables using `fopen` or `file_get_contents` depending which is quicker performance once I do so benchmarks.

I'm using the example code below

```
$file = 'http://example.com/get.php?var1=foo&var2=foo';
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
fpassthru($fp);
```

but it doesn't pass the `get` variables through. I don't want to use `cURL` just encase they don't have it installed and it seems to be slow also. I'm trying to make it very simple for the webmasters. How would I go about passing the variables through?

**Update**

I found if you have a space in the variable it stops sending the rest of the variable string. How do I allow spaces without it interrupting the rest of the variables? It also real buggy using multiple variables as it doesn't send them all for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On updated question - perhaps URL encoding the spaces in the variables - replace space with %20 may help.

Comment: I thought of doing that as I was typing the update but for some reason it still doesn't even send all the variables only like the first 2 when I'm using 5.

Comment: I think you'll need to give an example of the URL and parameters that you are using.  Tested using php and some variables against a test site here, and saw same behaviour when a space was in the line, fixed by encoding it.  Not sure what other characters may cause you a problem.  Perhaps you could try running urlencode() over the values of each of the variables before adding the the URL in $file.

Comment: I tried urlencode and it works just had a typo the 5th var instead of `&` I had `$`.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used file_get_contents with URLs. Please check your PHP.ini to make sure that `allow_url_fopen=On` and also `urlencode` your variable, as mentioned in another question.

(*don't just replace the ' ' to %20*)